# How to Automatically change the focus of Windows Explorer to a highlighted file? - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, selection, focus

I have a very strange question. It is about automatically changing the focus to the next file when the currently focused file is deleted.

I have here my scenario. When I want to delete something, I highlight it and press delete like [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M80CP.png)

After that, the next file is somehow semi-highlighted and are not being focused ([like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PRAa.png))

**Now my question is:**

- Is it possible to make the next file after the deleted file to be focused automatically without using `space`, `ctrl + space`, and `clicking`? ([like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwVxB.png))

**Additional Information:**

- My operating system is Windows 10 21H1
- I'm using the default windows 10 explorer but just with a different Theme

I hope someone can help me with this problem

Answer (score 1):

Pressing down-arrow then up-arrow, e.g. - requires 2 keys, but is fairly facile solution to the use-case, which I too encounter.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: Start with the “semi-highlighted” scenario after deleting  a file as OP described. Press the down arrow, then the up arrow: result is the file above the deleted file’s former location is “fully” highlighted in focus. 
P.S.: Apologies for not using the key icon display originally, which appears unavailable in comments (ctrl – as suggested in forums changes zoom in my browser currently).